# Use SWIG for .cpp which depends on another .cpp

Tags: cmake, swig

I have a .cpp file which calls another .cpp file. I want to use SWIG to create a Python wrapper for this.
How do I make this using SWIG.
When I had a single .cpp file I was able to create a .so in the following manner:

```
//app.cpp
#include "app.hpp"
int p(int a)
{
std::cout<<"hello...SWIG runs fine!"<<std::endl;
return a;
}


//app.hpp
#include <iostream>
int p(int a);


//app.i
%module app
%{
#include "app.hpp"
%}
%include "app.hpp"
```

Commands run were:

- > swig -c++ -python app.i
- > g++ -Isrc -fPIC -I/../../../../usr/include/python3.6m
  >   -I/../../../../usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6m -lpython3.6m -c app.cpp app_wrap.cxx
- > g++ -shared -fPIC -o _app.so app.o app_wrap.o

**I was successful in generating a .so file with this method. However, now my app.cpp needs to use a function defined in another .cpp file *(a function called int fn1(int x) in hello.cpp)*. How do I generate .so now? If anyone could provide a small example it'd be great!**

**EDIT:**: Someone suggested I would have to use SWIG and CMAKE together. Is this true? If yes, how can I do so?

Comment: You should take a look at https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-swig (still work in progress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

> swig -c++ -python file1.i
>
> g++ -Isrc -fPIC -I/../../../../usr/include/python3.6m
>   -I/../../../../usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6m -lpython3.6m -c file1.cpp file2.cpp file1_wrap.cxx
>
> g++ -shared -fPIC -o _file1.pyd file1.o file2.o file1_wrap.o

Turns out we can use CMake to define dependencies and do this process automatically.
Also, SWIG can be used with CMake as mentioned on SWIG documentation [Introduction_build_system](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Introduction.html#Introduction_build_system)